# How to target the MuiChip borderRadius in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to reduce the border radius on a chip component any idea how to target it right ? I tried to target the root class, here is my experimental sandbox.

[image: Codesandbox Example]

Comment: i upvoted as question seemed fine to me. i want the answer also and i found it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in many ways but using `makeStyles` like you do:

```
"& .MuiChip-root": {
  borderRadius: 1
}
```

See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dfmc2?file=/demo.tsx:372-424)

Also radius on borders is called `border-radius` in CSS or `borderRadius` in MUI js based styles, not "borderRadious"..

Comment: this is on a div, how do you add it to the chip component itself?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you misspelled `borderRadius` as `borderRadious`, it should be the former.

Second, the value for no border radius is 0, and not `"none"`

Third, a better way to use `classes` is just to supply them as a prop to your `Chip` component, like `<Chip classes={classes} /*rest of the props*/ />`

The `classes` that worked for me is

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      borderRadius: 0,
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Give these `classes` to all your chips and you're good to go